# Passing output of bash expression to variable piped through a dialog progressbox results in null value for the variable

Tags: bash, dialog, wifi, stdout, command-substitution

I am using `dialog Version: 1.3-20190211` wiht `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release` and have the following script snippet which scans for networks on wlan0.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# duplicate file descriptor 1 on file descriptor 3
exec 3>&1

# Scan for networks and inform the user of scan in progress
scan=$(iwlist wlan0 scan) | dialog --backtitle "Secure WiFi Bridge - $(hostname)" \
                                   --title "Scan in Progress" \
                                   --clear \
                                   --progressbox "Scanning for networks in range..." 0 0 2>&1 1>&3

# Close file descriptor 3
exec 3>&-

clear
echo "$scan"
```

This does indeed run the scan, and brings up the dialog, however; the `$scan` variable is blank when trying to use it later in the script.  `echo "$scan"` above is only for demonstration purposes to show that the output is null.  How can I set the `$scan` variable while displaying the `progressbox`?

**UPDATE**

I realize that I could change `scan=$(iwlist wlan0 scan) | dialog` with `iwilst wlan0 scan > /tmp/scan_result | dialog`, and I could then read the file into the variable with `scan="$(cat /tmp/scan_result)"`, but I would prefer to avoid the use of writing/reading to/from a file if at all possible.

Comment: `scan=$(iwlist wlan0 scan)` doesn't produce any output at all, so `dialog` doesn't get any input from the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to obtain the desired result with a slight change of tactic.  Since piping through `progressbox` seemed to cause `$scan` to be populated in a subshell, I opted to simply pipe in a simple `printf` statement and removed the `--clear` option from the `dialog` declaration.  This left the `progressbox` displayed while `scan=$(iwlist wlan0 scan)` ran.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# duplicate file descriptor 1 on file descriptor 3
exec 3>&1

# Inform the user that a scan is in progress
printf "Scanning for networks in range...\nPlease wait..." | dialog \
    --backtitle "$APP_TITLE" \
    --title "Scanning Networks" \
    --progressbox 10 40 2>&1 1>&3

# Perform the scan
scan=$(iwlist wlan0 scan)

# Close file descriptor 3
exec 3>&-

clear
grep -E "SSID|Authentication" <<<"$scan"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, this helped me with a similar problem.